# Find total no of days spent by people from entry and exit day in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
day    entry_persons      exit_persons
 1         4               0
 2         2               1
 3         3               4
 4         5               0
 5         0               1
```

So basically for 5 days people are entering to and taking exit to a campus, I want to calculate the total no of days people stayed inside. For example,

```
day 1 -- 4 people
day 2 -- 4(from previous day)+2(current day)-1(exit), so 5
day 3 -- 5+3-4 so 4
day 4 -- 4+5 so 9
day 6 -- 9-1 so 8

so the output will be total no days spend by all people = 4+5+4+9+8 = 30
```

Looking for some pandas trick to do this efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subtraction and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['total'] = df['entry_persons'].sub(df['exit_persons']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   day  entry_persons  exit_persons  total
0    1              4             0      4
1    2              2             1      5
2    3              3             4      4
3    4              5             0      9
4    5              0             1      8
```

If you just want the total:

```
total = df['entry_persons'].sub(df['exit_persons']).cumsum().sum()
```

Or with a dot product:

```
total = (df['entry_persons'].sub(df['exit_persons'])
         .dot(np.arange(len(df), 0, -1))
        )
```

Output: `30`